# Django model retrieves same results

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models

I have a django model, TestModel, over an SQL database.

Whenever I do

```
TestModel.objects.all()
```

I seem to be getting the same results if I run it multiple times from the same process. I tested that by manually deleting (without using ANY of the django primitives) a line from the table the model is constructed on, the query still returns the same results, even though obviously there should be less objects after the delete.

Is there a caching mechanism of some sort and django is not going to the database every time I want to retrieve the objects?

If there is, is there a way I could still force django to go to the database on each query, preferably without writing raw SQL queries?

I should also specify that by restarting the process the model once again returns the correct objects, I don't see the deleted ones anymore, but if I delete some more the issue occurs again.

Comment: I don't know Django well at all, but last time I had a similar problem I realized I wasn't using the database I thought I was. You haven't changed the path recently or anything, have you?

Comment: @PeterBB I updated the description, I am sure I am using the correct database because the changes get updated with every restart of the process that's using the model.

Comment: THis happens between web requests or at shell level?

Comment: Very peculiar.  Can you provide your version of Django and DB?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your database isolation level is repeatable read. In a django shell all requests are enclosed in a single transaction.

**Edited**

You can try in your shell:

```
from django.db import transaction
with transaction.autocommit():
    t = TestModel.objects.all()
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a db transaction issue. If you're keeping a shell session open while you separately go into the database itself and modify data, the transaction that's open in the shell won't see the changes because of isolation. You'll need to exit and reload the shell to get a new transaction before you can see them.

Note that in production, transactions are tied to the request/response cycle so this won't be a significant issue.

Comment: This is a very significant issue to take in mind in production. Because a high isolation level causes more locks and a low isolation level may have computations implications.

Comment: I didn't mean that transactions themselves are not significant, just that you won't see this kind of inconsistency typically, because requests are short lived.